# SSL Pinning Alamofire works with any certificate

Tags: ios, swift, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am new to programming in general so it has been hard for me to understand the concept so please be considerate,
I have created an instance of a manager

```
import Alamofire

class SSLManager: SessionManager {

static let instance = SSLManager()

var manager: SessionManager?

 func sslPinning() {

    let hostname = "My Host Link"
    let cert = "_stackexchangecom" 


    let pathToCert = Bundle.main.path(forResource: cert, ofType: "der")
    let localCertificate = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToCert!)
    let certificates = [SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificate!)!]


    let serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(
        certificates: certificates,
        validateCertificateChain: true,
        validateHost: true
    )
    let serverTrustPolicies = [hostname: serverTrustPolicy,"insecure.expired-apis.com": .disableEvaluation]
    let serverTrustPolicyManager = ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)


    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let afManager = SessionManager(
        configuration: sessionConfiguration,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: serverTrustPolicyManager
    )
    self.manager = afManager
}
```

}

but my get request always returns with data even when using stackoverflow certificate

Comment: There are a few ways to implement Cert Pinning. Is your server presenting an expired leaf but a good Root CA? Is the leaf misnamed (common name mismatch)?  Update your question and that will make it simpler to focus on the answer.

Comment: A related article: https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/ssl-pinning-revisited

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the server I checked the same api and server are working with another developer I think the problem is with my implementation

Comment: @MohamedFarid have you found the answer?